# Getting a specific div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the properties of a certain div. However, Jquery seems to be returning an empty object and no changes seem to be happening.I require the div highlighted in blue. How do I access it?

[image: using firebug to view the HTML]

[image: Getting an empty object back]

Comment: Nice picture. Please post a [mcve] in your question and show us what jQuery you've tried.

Comment: [`$('.countiesMapInp')`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: Which code did you try with? Please also paste the code, not as an image.

Comment: What happens when you try `$(".countiesMapInp")`?

Comment: @freedomn. You just solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just curious, is this class unique on the page? Is a click initiating the color change? If so, an event listener might be in order...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns empty because you are accessing it as a tag, not a class. The dot is important.

Do `$('.countiesMapInp').css('background-color', 'yellow');`

Comment: Don't forget to vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about the dot. I"ll mark this as the right answer in a few minutes.